# Why is the object on the right being selected when I select the object on the left?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, mirror

I need to understand the reason of a specific behaviour. I'm in *Object mode* and when I select one feather on the left wing, automatically the corresponding feather on the right wing lights up, BUT I have no *Mirror modifier*, no *X mirror*, no *Topology mirror* activated. Do you know if there are others reason that explain this behaviour?

Check the attached video below:

[attached video](https://sendvid.com/zfld8nzo)

Comment: it would be helpful if you would add screenshots to your post, and upload a copy of your ~.blend file to <http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/> or a similar site, and edit a link to the file into your answer.

Comment: Should they be two distinct objects? At first sight, looks like you have applied the mirror modifier.

Comment: Yep, it looks like they are not two objects at all

Comment: You could try checking both the highlited and the selected objects in the 'Outliner' panel, see if they are linked.  I've cured a few problems this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the very beginning of your movie, while you're still in `Edit Mode` you can see that both feathers are actually one object with two unconnected mesh parts.

[image: Unconnected mesh parts]

When you select one of the feathers, the other one is highlited as well because it is the same object.